# Why setInterval is not in thousand milliseconds?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this w3school code with I am trying to use. However, I don't understand why the setInterval in this example is only 5 and not 5000. Isn't it supposed to be in thousands? And if not, then how can I do this animation faster? Because, everytime I decrease it down to decimals (like 0.01) the animation almost takes the same amount of time as it does now!

http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_dom_animate_3

Comment: it's 5ms. Why would it be 5s?

Comment: What do you think would happen if you set it to `5000`? You can try it out, you know?

Comment: `5ms` is about 200fps. Why would you expect it to go any faster? You should be using `requestAnimationFrame` and delta timing for smooth animations...

Comment: css animations might be better too!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Screen monitors can take render up to 60fps. Isn't it?

Comment: It's in thoudand**TH**s, not thousands.

Comment: I am sorry, if my question offended the guidelines of this community. I never intended to do so. However, I feel that my question consists of enough information that I could think of. Still if you feel that it does not consists relevant or enough information, I believe it might be because I am a beginner in this language. But, I think by putting my question on hold won't help me in anyways whatsoever. Therefore, I would like to request the community to help me rather than flagging this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a beginner question, but not a stupid question; I'm sorry you're getting such snarky comments above.

> I don't understand why the setInterval in this example is only 5 and not 5000

The interval defines how much time in milliseconds the code waits before running again -- an interval of 5000 would cause it to move once every five seconds. An interval of 5 causes it to run once every 5ms, or (theoretically) 200 times every second.  But see below...

> every time I decrease it down to decimals the animation almost takes the same amount of time as it does now

...processing time within each run-through is not taken into account; setInterval controls only the amount of delay between run-throughs.  So a very small interval as you have here is likely going to be overwhelmed by the time taken to do each run; below a certain point (which will be dependent on the user's processor speed) shorter intervals will not make your code run faster.

If you want the animation to appear to run faster, instead of trying to run more loops, you'll need to move the object farther per loop.  This'd require two changes to your code:

```
  function frame() {
    if (pos > 349) { // <-- here
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      pos = pos + 2;  // <-- and here
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; 
    }
  }
```

The second change is obvious enough -- instead of moving the item 1 pixel per loop, it'll move it 2 pixels per loop, doubling the speed.

The first one is to prevent endless loops: since you're adding larger increments to `pos` it might skip right past 350, so you need to avoid potential endless loops by instead checking to see if `pos` is greater than 349.

Comment: _The interval defines how much time in milliseconds the code waits before running again_
I would change it to _before trying to run it again_. Since JavaScript is single-threaded and it can't run code if the thread is busy.

Comment: Amazing :) Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval() call is only 5 because you want the red square to move multiple pixels each second. To see how fast the square is moving, divide 1000 (one second) by the value in the setInterval call. 1000 / 5 = 200 pixels of movement per second.

If you change the setInterval() value to some other number, the animation on the right will run at the same speed as before unless you click the "See Result >>" button at the top center. The "See Result >>" button is what copies your modified code from the left side to the right side.